# Extract formula from linear models list

Tags: r, list, formula

I am new to modeling in R. I have created a list of +/- 800 linear models, which looks like this, and from which I would like to choose the one that provides best forecasts:

```
    $`123`
    prod.index.rnd ~ prod.index.diff + Comp.1 + Comp.3
    <environment: 0x000000000a39dad8>

    $`124`
    prod.index.rnd ~ prod.index.diff + Comp.3
    <environment: 0x000000000a38f8b8>

    $`125`
    prod.index.rnd ~ prod.index.diff + Comp.1 + Comp.2
    <environment: 0x000000000a312408>
```

I would like to pick just the formula from each, to use it with the forecast function, so the final form would be:

```
    prod.index.rnd ~ prod.index.diff + Comp.1 + Comp.3
    prod.index.rnd ~ prod.index.diff + Comp.3
    prod.index.rnd ~ prod.index.diff + Comp.1 + Comp.2
```

Pls what is the way this can be done? I got stuck here... Thank you!

Comment: Can you please create a minimal reproducible example?  Perhaps leverage some of the sample datasets within R.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your models are in `your.list`:

```
lapply(your.list, formula)
```

Comment: I already tried that, but it remained in the prior format and when forecast function is used, i het error:

Error in x - fits : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(x, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA